# Doing a format string substitution within a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am currently trying to figure out if there is a way kind of 'soft code' the values in a dictionary, and be able to substitute a fixed string into those values places later on. In other words, just like how we can, with strings, do something like:

```
environment = """{'SDC_PERIOD':'%(period)s','FAMILY':'%(legup_family)s','DEVICE_FAMILY':'"%(fpga_family)s"','DEVICE':'%(fpga_device)s'}""" % self
```

and substitute the given desired values into the `environment` string object with the `self` instance namespace dictionary, I would like to be able to actually directly do the substitution into the dictionary itself, perhaps something like below?

```
environment = {'SDC_PERIOD':'%(period)s','FAMILY':'%(legup_family)s','DEVICE_FAMILY':'"%(fpga_family)s"','DEVICE':'%(fpga_device)s'} % self
```

However, I know this is not allowed as the `%` operand is not supported for dictionary object types, so the above line does not work, but I'm just using it to express my objective to be able create a dictionary from substituting string objects into 'soft coded' values.

Right now, as I do not know of any way to be able to substitute in strings into the dictionary values, I have no choice but to do the following:

```
import ast
environment = """{'SDC_PERIOD':'%(period)s','FAMILY':'%(legup_family)s','DEVICE_FAMILY':'"%(fpga_family)s"','DEVICE':'%(fpga_device)s'}""" % self
env_dict = ast.literal_eval(environment)
```

in order to be able to get the dictionary object with the desired key:value pairs.

However, this seems to be too much for just something so simple as getting a dictionary object with the right key-values. I would appreciate if anyone has any other suggestions for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Perrhaps I'm not understanding this but is there some reason you can't just build the dictionary directly with things like `environment = { 'SDC_period': self.period }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do some complex interpolation on the strings comprising `dict` values (or any string, for that matter), you can use `format`.

```
>>> period_val  = "1970"
>>> family_val = "Smith"
>>> environment = {'SDC_PERIOD': '{period}s'.format(period = period_val), 'FAMILY': '{legup_family}s'.format(legup_family = family_val)}
>>> print environment
{'SDC_PERIOD': '1970s', 'FAMILY': 'Smiths'}
```

For simpler strings like the above, I would probably use number references instead (i.e. `{0}`, since it's less typing), and for no interpolation situations, I would assign the values directly using the variable, but for more complicated interpolation, say if you were interpolating 3 or 4 variables into one string, referencing things by name can help the code become clearer.

Here's some more info on [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding but perhaps you could just build the dictionary directly like so:

```
environment = {
    'SDC_period': '{0}s'.format(self.period),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always subclass `dict` and give it a new method that combines the `__getitem__` and `%` operations. I'll call that method `interpolate`:

```
class envdict( dict ):
    def interpolate( self, key, replacements ):
        return self[ key ] % replacements

environment = envdict( SDC_PERIOD='%(period)s' )
val = environment.interpolate( 'SDC_PERIOD', { 'period' : 'whatever' } )
print val
```